# MySQL: JOIN where ON may compare with null

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have:**

```
simple_table
  |- first_id
  |- second_id

SELECT * FROM table t1 JOIN table t2
ON [many many conditions]
ON t1.id IN (SELECT first_id FROM simple_table)
AND t2 = (
    SELECT second_id FROM simple_table WHERE t1.id = first_id //4th row, can return NULL
)
```

**Questions:**

1. How to handle situation  where `4th` row return null?
2. Can I use `t1` & `t2` alias inside subqueries?

**Updated [extra wxplanation]**

I have very big `table`. I need to iterate through table and check some conditions. Actually `simple_table` provide the ids of `table` entities, conditions of which I should check. I mean:

```
  simple_table
first_id second_id
   11      128

    table    
id  <other_fields>
................
11  <other_data>
...............
128  <other_data>
```

So, I should check whether those two entities in `table` have right conditions relatively one another.

Comment: `ON` is to state joining condition, what you write are more `WHERE` condition, also `=` is for simple equality and `AND t2` is probably `AND t2.id`

Comment: Can you supply some sample data and desired results?

Comment: @Serpiton but `WHERE` can reduce performance, right? I have deal with big data (mean `table1` and `table2`)

Comment: Cross join reduce the performance even more if it's not what you want to do and I don't see any join condition between table1 and table2, it seems a many to many join with simple_table as the junction table, in that case you should join all the three of them

Comment: @Serpiton yes, I just simplified query for you. Look at updated version please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is unclear, but given the update the query should work better if there is an index on the ID of the big table (probably it's there already as the `PK`).

As the condition seems to be on the same table the easiest query will be

```
SELECT ...
FROM   bigtable t1
       INNER JOIN simple_table st ON t1.ID IN (st.first_id, st.second_id)
```

or

```
SELECT ...
FROM   bigtable t1
       INNER JOIN simple_table st ON t1.ID = st.first_id
       INNER JOIN bigtable t2 ON st.second_id = t2
```

to get the two rows from bigtable on the same row of the result.
The second query will make the checks easier to write, the first will be faster but most probable need a `GROUP BY` to return the wanted results.

Some performance tests on the OP machine are needed to get the fastest one.

In case one of the ID in `simple_table` is `NULL` only the other will be considered, the code will have to check about it.

You can use the alias of the tables in the subqueries, and you'll need to do that as you'll probably have the same table in the subqueries.

The relative condition to check are still undisclosed by the OP so that's all I can help with.